# IMAP connection tracking

Tags: php, imap

Is there a way to track the live connection time of imap_open()? I have tried imap_timeout() but it just takes the timeout set in the php.ini. What I want to achieve here is to check how long it takes before the connection errors (something like wrong username).

```
 $mbox = imap_open($this->data['ServerName'], $this->data['UserName'], $this->data['PassWord']);
    $time = time();
    // $mbox = imap_open("{}INBOX", "", "");

    $x = imap_timeout(IMAP_OPENTIMEOUT);
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($x);
            echo "</pre>";
    var_dump(time() - $time);
    if ($hdr = imap_check($mbox)) {
        echo "Num Messages: " . $hdr->Nmsgs ."\n\n<br><br>";

        return $mbox;
    } else {
        // error_log("Connection Failed. Could not Connect to the Mail Server", 0);
        // $this->sendErrorMail("Connection Failed. Could not Connect to the Mail Server");
        die("Connection Failed. Could not Connect to the Mail Server");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

imap_timeout takes parameters. The one you want is the constant IMAP_OPENTIMEOUT.

`echo imap_timeout(IMAP_OPENTIMEOUT);`

Comment: I already tried it. I updated the code above but it still returns like 60 seconds and I also displayed the exact time before the connection was error it is not the same.